# How to Exclude Directories from grep command in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find, sh

I Am trying to exclude directories from grep matches, i have tried with `--exclude-dir=PATTERN` method. But its not working.

`ls | grep -E "^Acct" --exclude-dir=Acct`

File Structure

```
Acct/ ---> directory needs to be excluded from grep
AcctReq/ ---> directory needs to be excluded from grep
AcctAdd.txt
AcctInq.txt     
AcctMod.txt       
AcctTrnInq.txt
CardInq.txt
CardHold.txt
Cardacq.txt
```

In Above files I am using `ls | grep -E "^Acct"` command to get only the files starting with `Acct`, But it is considering the directories as well.

Output:

```
Acct/
AcctReq/
AcctAdd.txt
AcctInq.txt     
AcctMod.txt       
AcctTrnInq.txt
```

Expected Output:

```
AcctAdd.txt
AcctInq.txt     
AcctMod.txt       
AcctTrnInq.txt
```

Comment: `--exclude-dir` can only be used when you're grepping files with the `--recursive` option, not piped input. It tells it which directories to skip when recursing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--exclude-dir` is used to skip directories when running a recursive grep. It's meaningless when you're piping input to `grep`, since there are no directories or filenames to skip.

If you want to exclude matches from the data being piped to `grep` use `-v`.

```
ls | grep -v 'Acct.*/'
```

Comment: Actually this is part of the script, am patching this grep inside for loop, it is not actually considering the "/" which is there in the folder name.
``` for i in `ls | grep -E "^Acct" | grep -v 'Acct.*/'`;do echo $i;done```

Comment: `ls` doesn't output `/` after the directory unless you use `ls -F`. I assumed `ls` was an alias since you're getting `/` in the output.